# Why is prepending to a list instantaneous?

Tags: haskell

I am going through an Haskell tutorial about lists, and it claims:

> Watch out when repeatedly using the ++ operator on long strings ... Haskell has to walk through the whole list on the left side of ++. ... However, putting something at the beginning of a list using the : operator (also called the cons operator) is instantaneous.

But, in my mind, things should be the other way around.

`:` has to go through all elements in the list because it needs to shift all the indices. `++`, on the other hand, can just append a new element at the end of the list and be done with it, hence instantaneous.

Any help understanding this statement?

Comment: It sounds like you're just mixing up arrays with lists.

Comment: This could be implemented using a linked list, without keeping a pointer to the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list in Haskell is just a singly-linked list. A list of, say, `Char`, is either `[]`, the empty list, or `c : cs`, where `c` is a `Char` and `cs` is a list of `Char`. To produce `c : cs` given `c` and `cs`, all the implementation needs to do is allocate a record with a tag indicating `(:)` and copies of the pointers `c` and `cs`. This is extremely cheap.

Comment: So I guessed right :) Any reference for this? Can it be considered "part of Haskell", or are implementations free to do it otherwise?

Comment: @Jongware I suppose if you guessed that linked lists are implemented using linked lists, you guessed right. I would be surprised if an implementation used something other than a linked list to implement a linked list.

Comment: @DanielLyons: but I don't know Haskell and the question does not call them *linked* lists. Lists can be implemented in various ways - and all of these would behave slightly different with the operations that OP mentions. From the observed behavior, I deduced that thus lists must be implemented as linked lists.

Comment: @Jongware The spec indeed does not demand that `[a]` be implemented as a linked list -- only that it behave as one. In fact, even "behave" does not include runtime considerations beyond "halts or doesn't"; so an implementation would be free to use arrays if out could preserve the semantics. I believe all extant implementations implement the `[a]` type as a linked list.

Comment: @Jongware, `[]` and `(:)` are the *data constructors* of the list type. They have weird special syntax, but you can make all sorts of datatypes that work in the same fashion. For example, `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` or `data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, implementing Haskell lists as arrays would produce extremely befuddled and annoyed Haskell programmers.

Comment: @dfeuer Except for Haskell programmers who learn using DWC instead of GHC.  Seriously, though.  It would be interesting to replace the list implementation with something like a rope implementation in the compiler.

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson, I couldn't figure out what you meant by "DWC". Also, I think GHC's overloaded lists mechanism is nicer than actually replacing lists.